# Dynamic COM object 1-indexed array InvalidCastException bug

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamic, com

I have a COM API that I use in a C# .NET 4.0 application.

The code looks like this:

```
if (!object.ReferenceEquals((comObject.Value), null))
{
   // Do something
}
```

Where `comObject` is of type `System.__ComObject` and `Value` is of type `dynamic`.

In general this works fine, however when the actual type of `Value` is a byte array it throws with the following `InvalidCastException` exception:

```
   Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[*]' to type 'System.Byte[]'.

   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
   at ReMetricaTypeSpike.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ReMetricaTypeSpike\ReMetricaTypeSpike\Program.cs:line 28
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

This thread http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/24c0bd62-058a-487e-91ab-ed1bb0b0cca4 seems to suggest that the exception is being thrown because the array is 1 based (it is - I think the API was written in VB). However, I never make this cast explicit, that is all handled by the dynamic automagic code.

Is this a known bug with C# dynamic? Or is there something else going on?